# Get Server-side cookies in angular SSR (universal) in authService to get logged in information

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I have used ngx-cookie-service to set cookies in client-side. Then I have an interceptor which passes the cookie to angular server side. I now need to get the cookies in auth service and check if the user is authenticated in the server side rendered page of the application. I tried injecting the REQUEST object from express, but I can find a proper JSON formatted cookie item. Is there any other way I can get this?

Comment: Do you get the cookie string at least in `request.headers.cookie`? Also, the problem with ngx-cookie-service is that it does not support angular universal (https://github.com/stevermeister/ngx-cookie-service/issues/1)

Comment: Yes I got the cookie string. I need to convert that  into a JSON now. Also I have a JSON object as value in one the keys in the cookie.

i.e. { accessToken: 'something', refreshToken: 'refreshToken', user: { id: 1, name: 'abc' .... }}. I have to get it out in this format.

Comment: Maybe try using express cookie parsed middleware, or parse the string yourself?

Comment: Thanks @David. Used the cookieParser middleware.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how can you use ngx-cookie-service server side, since it's not supported?

Comment: @David. I didn't use ngx-cookie-service now. :D Went with the express request body and cookieParser middleware.

Comment: Ok, thanks for letting me know